# Having some trouble with making sure an object exists in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on some code for a project, and I'm in need to find out how to **NOT** make my code return errors each time I run it with the failsafes I have. (I don't want it overwriting files for no reason)

Copy both the code into python and link it to the path of line 1 saying:
"genericcity"

```
file = r"YOUR FILE PATH HERE" # loads the file
memory = open(file, "r+") # opens the file in read & write mode
city = memory.readlines()[0].lower() # sets the city to line 1 of the file and lowercases it
cityfail = 0 #makes a variable to check if the process failed

cities = { # creates a nested dictionary to add the cities
    "genericcity" : { #creates a city
        "rent" : 1, #rent of the city
        "density" : 1 #population density of the city
    },
}   

if cities.get(city): # checks if the county in the text file is valid
    if (input == "rent" or input == "density") : # makes sure it's not rent or density, two other variables inside dictionary
        cityfail = 1 # if so, makes sure the script fails
else: # if not in the text file,
    cityfail = 1 #fail the scipt

if (cityfail == 1) : # immediate failing of the script
    print("ERROR: UNKNOWN COUNTY:") # error
    print("Confirm that the city you selected in the TextFile.txt file is in the script.") # instructional message
    quit() # ends the script
```

Right at the end of the script it completley cuts off access to the rest of the program, even though the file says on line 1 "genericcity". Running it just returns "None" which is the main problem. Since "None" is non-existant in the code it errors out.

Further on I intend to enter the code that reads the entered info, but I wasn't able to reach it in the first place.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but remember to close files after reading them. So `with open(file, "r+") as memory:` indent `input = memory.readlines()[3]`.

Comment: `input` it's a built-in function. Better not overwrite it.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are asking; what you expect your code to do; or how it is deficient; or if is producing an Exception. When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question, especially if that data is from an external resource.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. Please read [mcve].

Comment: AndrewQ said, `input` is a built-in function, so you should choose a different variable name. This doesn't really meet the Verifiable condition of Minimal Complete Verifiable, since we don't have your file, and it's not really Minimal since it relies on that file. You should start by testing your code with `input= memory.readlines()[3].lower()` replcaed with `input = 'genericcity` and see whether it does what you expect. If it does, then then the problem is with reading from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `memory.readlines()[3]`. A line will have a trailing newline character, so you just need to strip it:

```
input_ = memory.readlines()[3].rstrip('\n').lower()
```

(Also BTW don't use `input` as a variable name since it's a built-in function.)

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the weird variable names and lack of reproduction abilities, fixed it in an edit.

Comment: @Jebus_irl No need to apologize, we all have to start somewhere :) But I'm not sure it's reproducible still, since some text editors won't add a trailing newline, Ace for example.

Comment: Oh, I just use bloody notepad since I'm too lazy to get anything else

Comment: Oh god no I'm not using notepad to code, using idle for that, just I need a seperate text doc for my code to read